# use math in footnotetext

Tags: footnotes

I'm trying to put some maths to add some details to an equation. But if the line in the footnotetext is too long it does not show up correctly.

```
   \begin{align*}
    a + b = C \text{\footnotemark}  \\
   \end{align*}

   \footnotetext{Reminder: obtain this by $F(45) = 1 \iff \frac{3}{100}*45 + b = 1  \iff b = -\frac{35}{100}$}
```

Do you have a way to write long maths expression in the footnote?

Comment: if you`re using `amsmath`, it should be possible to use `\[ ... \]` to put a displayed equation in a footnote.  and it's really not a great idea to launch a footnote from within a display; better to put it at the very end of the text that precedes the display.